# Check only prerequisites when running runInstaller in silent mode

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation, command-line

I want to check just prerequisites and generate a log without installing Oracle database.

When I run the following command:

```
./runInstaller -silentvalidate -responseFile /0/grid/response/crs_install_mk.rsp
```

It shows me the following error:

```
The command line arguments '-silentvalidate' are not valid options. Type 'oui -help' at the command line for instructions on appropriate command line usage.
Usage: runInstaller  [-options] [(<CommandLineVariable=Value>)*]
```

runInstaller has also an option `-executePrereqs` but it tries to launch installer in GUI mode.

So I want to check only prerequisites and generate log without launching a GUI.

Oracle Version: 11g R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

To check the prequisites in silent mode run the following:

```
./runInstaller -silent -executePrereqs -responseFile "/0/grid/response/crs_install_mk.rsp"
```

Comment: -silentvalidate doesn't work for 11gR2